Why does an error occur "npm error LRUCache is not a constructor" while im trying 'npm i"?
Have error every time i call npm install,
it doesnt matter nodejs version (tried 18,20,22) and where i call npm, globally or in project
>npm i -g pnpm@latest
npm error LRUCache is not a constructor

Tried reinstall a few versions of nodejs.
Do you have any idea what happen? I dont know even what is LRUCache, im not using it
My npm is 10.7.0

I opened /usr/lib64/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/memoization.js and found this line:
const { LRUCache } = require('lru-cache')

I changed it to this:
const LRUCache = require('lru-cache')

That's for Linux. On Windows, I think you would find memoization.js at:
C:\Users\<REPLACE WITH YOUR USER FOLDER'S NAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\memoization.js


already have :(
const LRUCache = require('lru-cache')

You'll want to look at a log. Add --loglevel verbose to your command for it to log everything to npm-debug.log in the current working directory upon failure, and it should give you more information on the potential problem file. Alternatively, run npm config get cache, and it'll give you the directory where the _logs folder is stored.
